# Wanting to number a list of randomly generated names in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I was wondering how to put numbers in front of this list in JavaScript.
I wrote this script to make some randomly generated names, and I've been struggling with numbering them. 
I already tried to number them via HTML but it wouldn't work.
If anyone could help me out it would mean a lot to me.

```js
var klinker = ["a", "e", "u", "i", "o"];
var medeklinker = ["q", "w", "s", "z", "x", "c", "v", "b", "n", "m", "d", "f", "g", "h", "j", "k", "l", "r", "t", "y", "p"];


function GenerateNPCNameF(lijst) {
    var loop = 0;
    var array = [];
    while (loop <= 99) {
        var klinker = ["a", "e", "u", "i", "o"];
        var medeKlinker = ["q", "w", "s", "z", "x", "c", "v", "b", "n", "m", "d", "f", "g", "h", "j", "k", "l", "r", "t", "y", "p"];

        var randomNumberKlinker = Math.floor(Math.random() * klinker.length);
        var randomKlinker = klinker[randomNumberKlinker];
        var randomNumberMedeklinker = Math.floor(Math.random() * medeklinker.length);
        var randomMedeklinker = medeklinker[randomNumberMedeklinker];

        var randomNumberKlinker1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * klinker.length);
        var randomklinker1 = klinker[randomNumberKlinker1];
        var randomNumberMedeklinker1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * medeklinker.length);
        var randomMedeklinker1 = medeklinker[randomNumberMedeklinker1];

        var randomNumberKlinker2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * klinker.length);
        var randomklinker2 = klinker[randomNumberKlinker2];
        var randomNumberMedeklinker2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * medeklinker.length);
        var randomMedeklinker2 = medeklinker[randomNumberMedeklinker2];


        array.push([randomKlinker + randomMedeklinker + randomklinker1 + randomMedeklinker1 + randomklinker2 + "<br>"]);

        loop += 1;
    }

    document.getElementById(lijst).innerHTML = array.join("");
}

GenerateNPCNameF("womanlist");
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Simple Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <style>

        </style>
        <h3>Female names</h3>
          <p id="womanlist">
          </p>

        <script src="script.js"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: why can't you use variable `loop` to add number to text? Or use an ordered list tag to have browser display numbers

Comment: When I add an ordered list tag the text just moves to the right a little

Comment: adjust the css then...not hard to research how or why it is like that

Answer (score 0):

```js
var klinker = ["a", "e", "u", "i", "o"];
var medeklinker = ["q", "w", "s", "z", "x", "c", "v", "b", "n", "m", "d", "f", "g", "h", "j", "k", "l", "r", "t", "y", "p"];


function GenerateNPCNameF(lijst) {
    var loop = 0;
    var array = [];
    while (loop <= 99) {
        var klinker = ["a", "e", "u", "i", "o"];
        var medeKlinker = ["q", "w", "s", "z", "x", "c", "v", "b", "n", "m", "d", "f", "g", "h", "j", "k", "l", "r", "t", "y", "p"];

        var randomNumberKlinker = Math.floor(Math.random() * klinker.length);
        var randomKlinker = klinker[randomNumberKlinker];
        var randomNumberMedeklinker = Math.floor(Math.random() * medeklinker.length);
        var randomMedeklinker = medeklinker[randomNumberMedeklinker];

        var randomNumberKlinker1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * klinker.length);
        var randomklinker1 = klinker[randomNumberKlinker1];
        var randomNumberMedeklinker1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * medeklinker.length);
        var randomMedeklinker1 = medeklinker[randomNumberMedeklinker1];

        var randomNumberKlinker2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * klinker.length);
        var randomklinker2 = klinker[randomNumberKlinker2];
        var randomNumberMedeklinker2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * medeklinker.length);
        var randomMedeklinker2 = medeklinker[randomNumberMedeklinker2];


        array.push([randomKlinker + randomMedeklinker + randomklinker1 + randomMedeklinker1 + randomklinker2 + "<br>"]);

        loop += 1;
    }

    var text = "";
    var i;
    for (i=1; i <= array.length; i++) {
      text += "" + i + ". " + array[i-1] + "<br/>";
    }
    document.getElementById(lijst).innerHTML = text;
}

GenerateNPCNameF("womanlist");
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Simple Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <style>

        </style>
        <h3>Female names</h3>
          <p id="womanlist">
          </p>

        <script src="script.js"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```